# Picasso not showing image

Tags: java, android, picasso, android-bitmap

I'm having a problem loading images with Picasso (*'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'*) in Moto G (2nd gen 5.0.2).
Here's the code:

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
          .cornerRadiusDp(cornerRadiusDp)
          .oval(false)
          .build();

        Picasso.with(MAPetApplication.getContext())
          .load(uri)
          .centerCrop()
          .resize(targetWidth, targeHeight)
          .transform(transformation)
          .into(imageView, new Callback() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess() {

              }

              @Override
              public void onError() {

              }
          });
```

While debugging I was able to notice that `void complete(BitmapHunter hunter)` method inside `Picasso.class` was returning a `null` result:

```
void complete(BitmapHunter hunter) {
...
 if(shouldDeliver) {
            Uri uri = hunter.getData().uri;
            Exception exception = hunter.getException();
            Bitmap result = hunter.getResult();
            Picasso.LoadedFrom from = hunter.getLoadedFrom();
            if(single != null) {
                this.deliverAction(result, from, single);
            }
...
}
```

***exception = java.io.IOException: Cannot reset***

Delivering:
result = null
from = "DISK"
single = com.square.picasso.ImageViewAction

```
 private void deliverAction(Bitmap result, Picasso.LoadedFrom from, Action action) {}
```

Instead of delivering:
result = android.graphic.Bitmap
from = "DISK"
single = com.square.picasso.ImageViewAction

resulting in a `action.error();`

What could it be?
Thanks.

ps: tested in Moto RAZRi 4.1.2, Nexus S 4.4.1, GT-I9505 4.4.2, Nexus 5 5.0.0/5.1.0, One Plus One 5.0.2, and it works fine.

Comment: Well it seams to be a known issue: "We are working on this for 2.5.3. Its a known issue. Dup #907" https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1018

Comment: dont use centercrop with resize